# add style for class in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Hi i created plugin for CKEDITOR. I want make a notice box. When user click to add notice-box button and fill forms. plugin create these source code:

```
<div class="notice-box">
    <i class="icon-info">info</i>
    <span class="notice-box__info">Lorem ipsum.... </span>
</div>
```

It all works fine. but now i want add some style for that. Styles for ckeditor level not for production. How can i add style for these classes for the CKeditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins and widgets can add their own stylesheet. For example:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'example', {
    init: function( editor ) {
        var pluginDirectory = this.path;
        editor.addContentsCss( pluginDirectory + 'styles/example.css' );
    }
} );
```

See the documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_styles).